# URL scheme not working

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Hello i'm new to React Native and mobile development.

I have created a url scheme in xcode.

[image: url scheme]

When i'm in the ISO simulator and open Safari and go to url `taddar_mobile_app://` Safari says "Safari cannnot open the page because the address is invalid." Therefore it doesn't open the app.

I have followed this tutorial https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/url-schemes.

What am i missing, does anyone know what's wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Kill safari and then open and try again, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a valid a URL scheme because it contains underscores.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-17

> Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a
> letter and followed by any combination of letters, digits, plus ("+"),
> period ("."), or hyphen ("-")